# how to solve this warning "'addressDictionary' was deprecated in iOS 11.0: Use @properties"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I need to get an address in a map and I use addressDictionary but in swift 4 is deprecated, How I can solve it?

[here is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sk1li.png)

Comment: What have you done so far to try to solve your problem?

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code. Please replace the image with your actual code, as text, copied and pasted into your question. Pictures can't be searched or referenced and they are harder to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.postalAddress`.

```
let address = loc.postalAddress
let street = address.street
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [better explanation](https://www.quora.com/What-should-I-do-when-the-Swift-compiler-says-I-need-to-use-properties-Isnt-that-Objective-C) for this warning:

> The error being described is a deprecation error on the addressDictionary property of a CLPlacemark instance. When a deprecated method is called, the Swift and Objective-C compilers can surface some information about why it’s deprecated and/or what you should do to resolve the problem; this information is (optionally) provide by the author of the API in question.
>
> In this case, the CLPlacemark implementation is in Objective-C, so the information was provided in its header file. Looking at that, we see: `@property (nonatomic, readonly, copy, nullable) NSDictionary *addressDictionary API_DEPRECATED("Use @properties", macos(10.8, 10.13), ios(5.0, 11.0), watchos(1.0, 4.0));` The API_DEPRECATED macro tells the compiler where the API was introduced, and when it was deprecated in each OS that makes it available.